# Lower bound for KL divergence of bounded densities and $L_{2}$ metric

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, it.information-theory

I am currently reading "Smoothing of Multivariate Data" by Klemela. It contains Lemma 11.6, which upper and lower bounds the KL-divergence of two densities in terms of the $L_{2}$-metric. The Lemma specifically states the following 2 bounds ***without*** proof:

**Upper bound**

> Let $f, f_{0}$ be densities. In particular, if $\inf _{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}} f_{0}(x)>0$, then
> $$
> D_{K}^{2}\left(f, f_{0}\right) \leq \frac{\left\|f-f_{0}\right\|_{2}^{2}}{\inf _{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d} f_{0}(x)}}
> $$

**Lower bound**

> Also, if $f$ and $f_{0}$ are both bounded and bounded away from zero, then
> $$
> D_{K}^{2}\left(f, f_{0}\right) \geq \int_{\left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}: f_{0}(x)>0\right\}}\left(f-f_{0}\right)+C\left\|f-f_{0}\right\|_{2}^{2}
> $$
> for a positive constant $C$.

I can prove the upper bound rigorously as follows:
\begin{align}
   D_{K}^{2}(f, f_{0}) 
   &\leq \chi^{2}(f || f_{0})
   \tag{well known upper bound} \\
   &=: \int_{\left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}: f_{0}(x)>0\right\}} \frac{\left(f-f_{0}\right)^{2}}{f_{0}} 
   \tag{by definition} \\
   &\leq \frac{1}{\inf _{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d} f_{0}(x)}} 
         \int_{\left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}: f_{0}(x)>0\right\}} 
         \left(f-f_{0}\right)^{2}
    \tag{since $\inf$ exists.} \\
    &=: \frac{\left\|f-f_{0}\right\|_{2}^{2}}{\inf _{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d} f_{0}(x)}}
\end{align}

Note here that the **definition** of the KL divergence used in the Lemma is as follows:

> If $f$ and $g$ are densities of $P$ and $Q$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, then we may write
> $$
> D_{K}^{2}(f, g)=\int_{\mathbf{R}^{d} \cap\{x: g(x)>0\}} f \log _{e}\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)
> $$

I'm unsure on how to prove the lower bound. Some comments (for the lower bound to hold):

- It appears that the densities here must also be bounded above (else see first counterexample [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393477/486152)).
- Since the densities are assumed to be bounded above and positively bounded from below over their common support, the support set in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ must also be bounded (else see second counterexample [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/393477/486152)).

Could anyone please show how to prove this **lower bound** rigorously (or provide a citable rigorous proof reference)? Also, if I've made a mistake in my two comments above, please also let me know.

**Aside:** I had originally posted this on math.SE. To respect math.overflow [cross-posting etiquette](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/1726/486152), I've deleted that post due to no responses. I realized that it had also been asked [there before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635261/kullback-leibler-divergence-is-equivalent-to-l2-norm-in-some-cases) without any suitable responses. Since it is a research related question with no well citable proof, I believe it is fair to post here on math.overflow to settle the issue.

Comment: What is $C$ allowed to depend on?

Comment: The condition $\inf _{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}} f_{0}(x)>0$ cannot hold for any pdf $f_0$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis - I believe that if the underlying densities are bounded by $[a, b]$ for some $0 < a < b < \infty$, then C should be a function of $(a, b)$. Moreover they should be defined on a common bounded support in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. The book is not precise on this, but per my comments above, I believe this is correct.

Comment: @IosifPinelis - right, per my comments in the original post, the underlying common support of $f, f_{0}$ should be assumed to be a **bounded** set, say $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then we can assume that $f, f_{0}$ range within $[a, b]$, for some fixed $0 < a < b < \infty$.

Comment: Should then $C$ be allowed to depend on $K$ as well?

Comment: @IosifPinelis - good question - I believe so, yes. So $C = C(a, b, K)$, per the notation in my previous comments. The book is not precise on this, but these boundedness assumptions (for support $K$ and range $[a, b]$, for the densities $f, f_{0}$, are necessary for the lower bound to hold. Otherwise the counterexamples in the OP apply to invalidate the lower bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ep}{\varepsilon}$As in your post and comments, suppose that $f$ and $f_0$ are supported on a compact set $S$, and
\begin{equation*}
    a\le f\le b,\quad a\le f_0\le b
\end{equation*}
on $S$ for some real $a,b$ such that $0<a<b$.

Then
\begin{equation*}
    \int_{\left\{x \in \mathbf{R}^{d}: f_{0}(x)>0\right\}}\left(f-f_{0}\right)
    =\int_S\left(f-f_{0}\right)=0. 
\end{equation*}
So, the inequality in question is simply is
\begin{equation*}
    D_{K}^{2}\left(f, f_{0}\right) \ge C\left\|f-f_{0}\right\|_{2}^{2}. \tag{1}\label{1} 
\end{equation*}
By definition,
\begin{equation*}
    D_K^2(f,f_0)=\int_S f\ln\frac f{f_0}=-\int_S f\ln\frac{f_0}f. 
\end{equation*}
We have the elementary inequality
\begin{equation*}
    \ln x\le(x-1)-\ep_M(x-1)^2 \tag{2}\label{2} 
\end{equation*}
for any real $M>1$ and all $x\in(0,M]$, where
\begin{equation*}
    \ep_M:=\frac{M-1-\ln M}{(M-1)^2}>0. 
\end{equation*}
Note that $0<\frac{f_0}f\le\frac ba$ on $S$. So, using \eqref{2} with $x=\frac{f_0}f$ and $M=\frac ba$, we get
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    D_K^2(f,f_0)&\ge-\int_S f\Big(\frac{f_0}f-1-\ep_{b/a}\Big(\frac{f_0}f-1\Big)^2\Big) \\ 
&   =\ep_{b/a}\int_S f\Big(\frac{f_0}f-1\Big)^2
     =\ep_{b/a}\int_S \frac{(f_0-f)^2}f \\ 
     &\ge\frac{\ep_{b/a}}b\,\int_S (f_0-f)^2
     =C_{a,b}\|f-f_0\|_2^2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    C_{a,b}:=\frac{\ep_{b/a}}b>0,  
\end{equation*}
as desired.

Comment: Thank you! This was insightful. I tried to use a similar approach, with a second order taylor expansion of $\log(x + 1)$. I like this approach.

Comment: @user4687531 : You are welcome.